# Docusign envelope AuthoritativeCopy is always null

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign SDK (c#) to retrieve information on an envelope I create and submit in which I set the Authoritative Copy setting. I get the envelope id however when I retrieve the envelope the property AuthoritativeCopy is always set to null.

If I download the API logs from the DocuSign console I can see that it's been set, here's a snippet from the JSON:

```
"authoritativeCopy": true
```

So I don't understand why I'm always getting `null` with the SDK. Am I misunderstanding what this property is supposed to be? Has anyone else run into this or something similar?

I also have the same issue with the field EnforceSignerVisibility, I made sure to turn on Document Visibility to "Must sign to view, unless sender" and I still always get `null` for the field. Again if I check the API logs I can see that it was enabled so why can't I see it via the Envelope object with the SDK? Could it be a permissions thing? I'm requesting a JWT user token to request envelope information.

Sample Request:

```
Request Headers:
"X-DocuSign-Authentication", "{"Username":"{{username}}","Password":"{{password}}","IntegratorKey": "{{integratorKey}}"}")

GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{{account}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}?advanced_update=true
```

Response:

```
{
"status": "sent",
"documentsUri": "/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/documents",
"recipientsUri": "/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients",
"attachmentsUri": "/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/attachments",
"envelopeUri": "/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}",
"emailSubject": "Document for eSignature",
"envelopeId": "{{envelopeId}}",
"signingLocation": "online",
"customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/custom_fields",
"autoNavigation": "true",
"envelopeIdStamping": "true",
"notificationUri": "/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/notification",
"enableWetSign": "true",
"allowMarkup": "false",
"allowReassign": "true",
"createdDateTime": "2019-03-20T19:48:57.6370000Z",
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-03-20T19:48:57.6370000Z",
"initialSentDateTime": "2019-03-20T19:48:59.2470000Z",
"sentDateTime": "2019-03-20T19:48:59.2470000Z",
"statusChangedDateTime": "2019-03-20T19:48:59.2470000Z",
"documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/documents/combined",
"certificateUri": "/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/documents/certificate",
"templatesUri": "/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/templates",
"brandId": "{{brandId}}",
"purgeState": "unpurged",
"is21CFRPart11": "false",
"signerCanSignOnMobile": "true",
"isSignatureProviderEnvelope": "false",
"allowViewHistory": "true"
}
```

The response to the above request does not include the property `enforceSignerVisibility` however if I download the API request logs I can see that it's been set:

```
...
...
"enableWetSign": "True",
"enforceSignerVisibility": "True",
"brandId": "",    
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`authoritativeCopy` is set by DocuSign. You can't set it via the API.

After you want to download an authoritative copy from DocuSign then the envelope will show `authoritativeCopy` == false.

`EnforceSignerVisibility` is different. It needs to be first enabled at the account level. See the Admin Tool screen **Sending Settings** and the settings for Document Visibility. You need to check the box `Allow sender to specify document visibility`

Comment: I'm a little confused because in the API logs I can see that the property is set so I expected the SDK to be the same. Regarding the `EnforceSignerVisibility` I don't have that option, I only have a dropdown but even when i set it to `"Must sign to view, unless sender"` the property still comes back `null` all the time

Answer (score 0):

If you have set `enforceSignerVisibility` as true after switching on DocVis under Admin then to fetch the `enforceSignerVisibility` value, you need to pass query parameter `advanced_update=true` in the `GET /envelopes` API call.

Comment: Is there a similar parameter for the SDK that you know of?

Comment: Yes its there, `GetEnvelopeOptions` inner class in `EnvelopesApi.cs`, `GetEnvelopeOptions` has a property `public string advancedUpdate {get; set;}`

Comment: With the SDK it still comes back as `null` even after setting `advancedUpdate`. With the REST API it doesn't show up at all

Comment: It shows up only when it was set via envelopeCreation call and advancedUpdate query param is used to fetch the Get /envelopes/{envelopeId} API call. Can you please capture DocuSign API logs to see what you are sending while creating an envelope, [DS API Logging](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) will show how to capture logs in DocuSign, and I would assume you have switched on DocVis with `Sender can set Must Sign To View, unless member of sending account`

Comment: Yes I turned on `Sender can set Must Sign To View, unless member of sending account` and when I retrieve the log `CreateAndSendEnvelope` I can see `"enforceSignerVisibility": "True",` but I when fetch `GET /envelopes/{envelopeId}?advancedUpdate=true` that property doesn't show up at all

Comment: Its not `advancedUpdate=true` instead it is `advanced_update=true`

Comment: Can you please update qs with your createenvelope API call JSON Req, and then also share the API call JSON Re which you are hitting in GET /envelopes/{envelopeId}?advanced_update=true as well.

Comment: I updated with as much information as I could. I unfortunately don't have access to the request that is been made to DS to create the envelope.

Comment: Still you are using `advance_update=true` instead of `advanced_update=true` (missing d in advanced)

Comment: Really sorry i posted the wrong request but I am using `advanced_update=true`, I just doubled checked, same results

Comment: Run `GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{{account}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}?advanced_update=true` this call again for the envelope where you have set `enforceSignerVisibility` as `true` and can you please share your complete response after redacting any critical data from the response

Comment: Updated question with response

Comment: can you send envelope with `enforceSignerVisibility` as `true`  and see if you are seeing DocVis working at the time of Signing? I do not see any reason why you are not seeing this value back in GET /envelopes call.